# how insert into for joomla 1.7

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

in joomla 1.7 I have employers and jobseekers. employers can see jobseekers profile page. I also use an employer account to see jobseekers profile page. I inserted a field on jobseeker table on the database to see whether I interviewed that jobseeker or not. I pulled out and can see $interview data on the profile page but Also I want to edit that data on the profile page.What I dont understand is query and insert into codes.here is the form

```
<form action="<?php echo JURI::current(); ?>" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>interview:</td>
<td><input class="inputbox" type="text" name="interview" id="interview"    
size="50"    maxlength="100" value="<?php echo $jobseeker->interview; ?>" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit"  value="Save" class="button" />
</form>
```

thanks in advance..

Comment: This question is of interest to me too.  While I can add data to a database using SQL and PHP outside of Joomla just fine, I cannot seem to get it to work inside Joomla.  Ay help on this question is much appreciated.

Comment: Check out http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase

Comment: You've just shown a bit of form code. Nothing to do with how you're handling the submitted data. You need to get into the background of how Joomla deals with this stuff, and then come back and ask specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

While developing a form in Joomla, you have to remember that the action of the form should always be `index.php` This is to ensure that there is only one entry point to the site.

Next, a form is generally submitted to a `controller`, which is extended from `JController` or any of its subclass. You can achieve this by introducing the following standard hidden fields in your form -

```
<input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_yourComponentName" />
<input type="hidden" name="task" value="yourController.yourFunction" />
```

Then write appropriate handling code in the controller class.